# Supporting Parents by Paying Monthly Payments Tax Benefits

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, charity

Each month I pay my parents $300 so they can support themselves. My father still works and so is my mother. They filed a joint return themselves. They DO NOT live with me.

Can I get any tax benefits for my monthly payments to my parents?

Comment: tax deduction questions require the country be specified.

Comment: This would like be viewed as a gift, not charity.  And while it should be well under the limit and thus not taxed itself, it won't give a tax benefit either.  But yes, please specify the location.

Comment: Myself and my parents are located in Houston, TX USA

Comment: Do they include the $300 per month as part of their earned income in their taxes?

Comment: You give them money so they can support themselves? That sounds like a contradiction.

Comment: @JohnFx I am not sure if I understand correctly. I give them $300 monthly so they can buy groceries, gas, pay house mortgage. Basically they use the money to do whatever they want. If I do not give them money then it will make harder life for them.

Comment: The point I was making is that you are supporting them by giving money, they aren't supporting themselves. However, I'm being nitpicky here.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I know that you could get a tax benefit for yourself is if you could claim them as dependents.  That would let you get an exemption for them, which isn't a lot anyway.

The fact that they don't live with you does not matter since they are your parents and there's an explicit rule allowing for that. (https://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch03.html#en_US_2015_publink1000170951)  You would still need to show that you provide more than 1/2 their support, that their gross income is less than $4000/yr, and they would have to file separately unless they met the exception on that one. (https://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch03.html#en_US_2015_publink1000170857)  Sounds like none of those apply in your case.

Comment: None of these apply in my situation! Thanks for the advice!